# USB 3.0 portable HD Compatibility and Backup

Tags: compatibility, usb-3, incremental-backup

I have noticed on specifications that some list what os they are compatible with. If the OS is not listed does that mean the usb HD will not work for example MAC. If it does not say its MAC compatible would it not work with MAC as well as Windows?

From my understanding can I not just create 2 partitions and use 1 for mac and 1 for windows?

Also I have noticed that some HD say that they have a feature to support time machine etc. Does this require certain software from the manufacterer itself and comes with the HD when bought or can you get this software from Internet if so I am looking for something that would backup from Windows and Mac. From windows it should back up certain folders compressed same with MAC? Is it possible to do incremental backups. This is for personal use not industry.

Comment: Many drives come with some sort of (semi-)automatic backup solution included, such as Seagate Dashboard or WD SmartWare or similar, which may support only specific OSes. There are better backup solutions available in general - both free and paid.

Answer (score 1):

Most hard drives will work fine with Mac, PC or Linux (and no doubt other distros), even if they don't specifically mention it - although you may need to reformat the drives.  You may need to be a bit careful with the disk layout and support for "Advanced Format"/GUID drives - but most drives of 2 gigs or smaller should not pose any major problems.

Answer (score 0):

Most that do not mention Apple are just formatted for a Windows system.  You should be able to format for your Mac.  However, some ship with OS specific software that you will not get if you buy a drive for PC.  Many will allow you to download so a quick check at the manufacturer site will tell you.

In any case, why not but the Mac drive in the first palce?